# Get (pointer to) calling object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have an object -a scheduler class-. This scheduler class is given member function pointers, times and the pointer to the object which created the scheduler.
This means I could do something as much as: `(pObject->*h.function)(*h.param);` Where pObject is the pointer to the original object, h a class which contains the `function` + void pointer `parameter` so I can pass arguments to the original function.
When I like to initialize this object I have the `explicit Scheduler(pObjType o);`  constructor (where pObjType is a template parameter).

When I create an object which should have this alarm I type:

```
struct A {
    typedef void (A::*A_FN2)(void*);
    typedef Scheduler<A*,A_FN2> AlarmType;
    A(int _x) : alarm(NULL)
    {
        alarm.SetObject(this);
    }
    AlarmType alarm
```

However this alarm-type puts quite a big limitation on the object: *if I forget to add a copy-constructor (to **A**) the class would get undefined behaviour.* The scheduler would keep pointing to the original object, and that original object might go out of scope, or even worse, might not.

Is there a method that when I copy my alarm (by default, so in the scheduler's copy-constructor) I can get the calling object (and pointer to that?)?
Or if that isn't possible, is it possible to throw a (compile) error if I forget to implement a copy-constructor for my structure? - And try to copy this structure somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have an opportunity to improve your design here, that may help you get rid of your worry.

1. It is usually a bad idea to pass
   around member function pointers. It
   is better to make your structs
   inherit from an abstract base class,
   making the functions you want to
   customize abstract virtual.
2. If you don't need copying, it is best
   to disallow it in the base class.
   Either by making the copy constructor and operator undefined and private,
   or by inheriting `boost::NonCopyable`.

Comment: The problem with 1. is that these are *currently* member functions.. But later I want to extend it and possibly give handles to (LUA) scripts, so they can be customized at design level instead of engine level.   The problem with 2 is that I actually NEED copying, but since there is no other demand for an non-default copy-constructor (I designed everything so that this wouldn't be needed) I hoped to prevent the need here to.

Comment: I don't see exactly either why the copy constructor is the big problem here - the dangling pointers come from destruction, not copying. No? So you need to unsubscribe at destruction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any kind of automatic copy construction semantics, then you're going to need to go to the CRTP- no other pattern provides for a pointer to the owning object.

The other thing is that you should really use a boost::/std::function<>, they're far more generic and you're going to need that if you want to be able to use Lua functions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to prevent the specific issue you're asking about is to make `Scheduler` noncopyable (e.g. with `boost::noncopyable`). This means that any client class incorporating a value member of type `Scheduler` will fail to be copyable. The hope is that this provides a hint for the programmer to check the docs and figure out the copy semantics of `Scheduler` (i.e. construct a new `Scheduler` for every new `A`), but it's possible for someone to get this wrong if they work around the problem by just holding the `Scheduler` by pointer. Aliasing the pointer gives exactly the same problem as default-copy-constructing the `Scheduler` instance that holds a pointer.

Any time you have raw pointers you have to have a policy on object lifetime. You want to ensure that the lifetime of any class `A` is at least as long as the corresponding instance of `Scheduler`, and as I see it there are three ways to ensure this:

- Use composition - not possible in this case because `A` contains a `Scheduler`, so `Scheduler` can't contain an `A`
- Use inheritance, e.g. in the form of the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
- Have a global policy on enforcing lifetimes of `A` instances, e.g. requiring that they are always held by smart pointer, or that cleaning them up is the responsibility of some class that also knows to clean up the `Scheduler`s that depend on them

The CRTP could work like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Scheduler {
    typedef void (T::* MemFuncPtr)(void);

Scheduler(MemFuncPtr action) : 
    action(action)
    {
    }

  private:
    void doAction()
    {
        this->*action();
    }

    MemFuncPtr action;
};

struct Alarm : private Scheduler<Alarm> {
    Alarm() : Scheduler<Alarm>(&Alarm::doStuff)
    {
    }

    void doStuff()
    {
        cout << "Doing stuff" << endl;
    }
};
```

Note that private inheritance ensures that clients of the `Alarm` class can't treat it as a raw `Scheduler`.